# Purpose of unit test asserts other than a simple truth test

Tags: unit-testing

I am unable to understand what other asserts can offer beyond what a fundamental assertion such as xUnit's `Assert.True` provides. What is the advantage of using other types of assertions in our unit tests?

Answer (score 4):

In JUnit I much prefer using Hamcrest (assertThat) for all my matching. I feel it gives more readable assertions. There are a large number of available matchers and the error messages are much more informative.

For example, assume you have a `List<String>`. In `assertTrue` it might be:

```
assertTrue(myList.size() == 3);
```

The error message for this if `expected true, got false`. Compare that to Hamcrest,

```
assertThat(myList, IsCollectionWithSize.hasSize(3));
```

or with static import

```
 assertThat(myList, hasSize(3));
 assertThat(myList, containsInOrder("first", "second"));
```

The error message for this is `expected collection with size 3, got list["blah", "blah" ...]`

There are additional matchers like `containsString`, `IsIterableContainingInOrder`, `IsIterableContainingInAnyOrder`, etc, etc, etc.

[Hamcrest](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/)

Answer (score 2):

Mainly for readability.
For example:

```
StringAssert.StartsWith('abc', s);
```

is probably more readable than:

```
Assert.True(s.StartsWith('abc'))
```

Some assertions though do other useful stuff, such as `Assert.Fail();`

Answer (score 1):

I guess it offers some readability. Assert.IsNotNull(obj) is more easy on the eye than Assert.True(obj != null)

Answer (score 0):

for readability. tests should be the documentation of your code.

whenever possible i use [fest assert](https://github.com/alexruiz/fest-assert-2.x/wiki/Using-fest-assertions) with plain old assertXXX without any expressions. if not possible (or requires to much work with predicates) i use [hamcrest](http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/wiki/Tutorial). using complex expressions with assertXXX is the last resort for me